# Is there a way to get all the possible return values of a method in C#?

Tags: c#

Suppose there's a method which returns `enum`. But it returns only a subset of all the values of the enumeration. Can I find out programmatically which values are obtainable?

Example. I have an `enum`, which describes color with 100 values. Method `GetCurrentTrafficLightsState` can return only 3 colors of 100. I want to pass the method `GetCurrentTrafficLightsState` into some other method and get 3 colors as response.

Comment: Give it all possible inputs?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking

Comment: Write a unit test for each possible input?

Comment: Reverse your method (if possible), than return value should be input and if some values aren't obtainable, it should lead to some error, in that case throw exception, than easily you can loop through enum and check for exceptions.

Comment: Suppose there's a method which returns the result of an API call to an unknown API, can we find out which values are obtainable?

Comment: It cannot be resolved with a unit test cause the set of inputs is infinite, like string parameter. But the set of return values is finite - it is a subset of an enum.

Comment: What do you mean by "obtainable"? You just want to see all the enum values? Take a look at the enum!

Comment: Suppose the method changes, but its return type does not.  Of what value is the information you've obtained then?  The possible return values are all possible values of the return type.  What is the actual problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: Short of using static analysis on the method's IL to find out what values it uses, no. And even that assumes the method loads constants, and doesn't do nasty stuff like compute the number of steps it takes for a particular Turing machine to halt and return that, when casted to an enum. (Or more prosaically, calls a virtual method to cough up the result.) In its most general form, your problem is undecidable, as in, there exists no algorithm that can do this for the general case.

Comment: Example. I have an enum, which describes color with 100 values. Method GetCurrentTrafficLightsState can return only 3 colors of 100. I want to pass the method GetCurrentTrafficLightsState into some other method and get 3 colors as response.

Comment: if you mean to write some code like using Reflection ... well that is not possible

Comment: You could profile your code with a line-by-line option. So you can see which `code blocks` are present in a function. Every code block represents a possible outcome (exit path).

Comment: For now, I see only one solution: parse C# source code and find 'return' keywords.

Comment: If you have the source code, you could use the Roslyn compiler to do static analysis on the method and extract all uses of that particular enum.
https://www.google.nl/search?q=roslyn+find+usages

Comment: I think this is a valid question with a valid answer - it seems that this problem can be reduced to the halting problem, at least to me. I do not think it deserves to be closed. I am not familiar enough with CS theory to answer the question myself, though.

Comment: @Aluminium: Your "traffic light" example implies that your modeling is wrong.  The type being returned by `GetTrafficLightState` should have only the possible states of a traffic light.  Not any color.  (Also note that traffic lights are more complex than just three mutually exclusive colors.)  You're approaching the problem from the wrong angle.  You don't write code to examine the method and determine if it's right, you mix your modeling to guarantee that it's right.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't. You cannot even determine if it will return at all, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem